# React Native with RxJS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, rxjs

I am using React Native with RxJS and up until now, whenever I subscribe to an observable I have been doing:

```
observable.subscribe(() => {
     this.setState({ loading: true });
}.bind(this));
```

But since I upgraded to React Native 0.16.0, everywhere I have performed bind(this) on an inline function declared with the ES2015 arrow notation, React Native picks it up as an error. However when I change the arrow notation back to ES5 regular function notation as below:

```
observable.subscribe(function() => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
}.bind(this));
```

The errors seem to go away.

What is going on here?

Comment: What are you trying to bind `this`? That seems like something you would have to do only if you are *not* using an arrow function?

Comment: .. I ageed with @azium. If you write ()=>{} then `this` from the outer scope is already bound in the function.

Answer (score 9):

When you use an arrow function you're already binding this to that particular function. So:

```
() => {} === function() {}.bind(this)
```

Comment: `() => { return this }() === function() { return this }.bind(this)()`

Comment: this should be the best answer @coldbuffet

Answer (score 0):

Related to your question, I would recommend also checking out FrintJS, which comes with React and React Native integration too: https://github.com/frintjs/frint-react-native

It ships with an `observe` higher order component, which allows you to stream props to your component using an RxJS observable, so your base component is always written as a stateless function.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { observe } from 'frint-react';

function MyComponent(props) {
  return <p>Interval: {props.interval}</p>;
}

export default observe(function () {
  // return an Observable emitting a props-compatible object here
  return Observable.interval(1000)
    .map(x => ({ interval: x }));
})(MyComponent);
```

More on this topic:

- [FrintJS on GitHub](https://github.com/frintjs/frint)
- [Streaming props to React component](https://medium.com/@fahad19/using-rxjs-with-react-js-part-2-streaming-props-to-component-c7792bc1f40f)
- [`observe` higher-order component](https://frint.js.org/guides/higher-order-components/)